# How to insert an eyeball texture into an eyeball mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, image, uv-image-editor

#### The Problem

When I try to adjust the texture of the eyeball with the resize eyeball object, the eyeball always appears black. I am currently at a loss.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: this question got 881 views within one hour? What makes it so popular?

Comment: Did you create a material and assign the texture as base color? Cycles or evee?

Comment: Hello, the problem has been solved. I have just appended the eye again to blender.